# After scaling the train and test data, the model score goes to 1, something doesn't seem right?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, svm

prescaled features
[image]

```
scaler.fit(x_train)
scaler.fit(x_test)
xts= scaler.transform(x_train)
xts=pd.DataFrame(xts, columns=x_train.columns)
xtest= scaler.transform(x_test)
xtest=pd.DataFrame(xtest, columns=x_test.columns)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC()
model.fit(x_train,y_train)
model.score(x_test,y_test)

score: 0.71-0.76
```

postscaled features

[image]

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train)
scaler.fit(x_test)
xts= scaler.transform(x_train)
xts=pd.DataFrame(xts, columns=x_train.columns)
xtest= scaler.transform(x_test)
xtest=pd.DataFrame(xtest, columns=x_test.columns)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = SVC()
model.fit(xts,y_train)
model.score(xtest,y_test)

score: 1.0
```

What can I do to fix this, am I just overthinking it? Is it normal to get this kind of results from this data?

Comment: If you convert dataframes into code snippets instead of images, everyone can reproduce your result and more probably you can get an appropriate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without more data to work on, but it is possible, especially given the dramatic impact of scaling on your dataset. Take a look at the impact of scaling in this below example. In a 2-d case it is easier to picture, and it's important to understand that a score of 1 indicates there is most likely no overlap of the different categories, and hence you can draw perfectly clean vectors (MMH) to divide the categories. Perhaps you could also consider taking the logarithm or reviews or so, given the large range of possible values?

[image: SVM - before and after scaling]